# Python and UIO devices: Why does mmap.read() work and os.read() fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux-device-driver, xilinx

Kernel version: 4.19
Python version: 3.5.6
Platform: Xilinx Ultrascale+ Zynq

I'm developing some python code that can read and write to a UIO device. I've found a way that works and a way that fails for no apparent reason that I can understand. I'm worried this means there is something about this whole approach that I've missed and will come back to bite me in the future.

For my initial testing, I'm reading and writing to a single register in the PL whose 5 LSBs are active.
Here's the working code:

```
>>> import mmap
>>> fid= open('/dev/uio0', 'r+b', 0) # read/write, binary, non-buffered
>>> regs= mmap.mmap(fid.fileno(), 4)
>>> regs.read(4)
b'\x1c\x00\x00\x00'
>>> regs.seek(0)
>>> regs.write(b'\xF3\x00\x00')
>>> regs.seek(0)
>>> regs.read(4)
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00'
```

And here are two examples of failing code:

Using just the standard read functions fails

```
>>> fid= open('/dev/uio0', 'r+b', 0) # read/write, binary, non-buffered
>>> fid.read(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Using os fails as well, but I can provide the file descriptor to mmap and everything works.

```
>>> fid= os.open('/dev/uio0', os.O_SYNC | os.O_RDWR)
>>> os.read(fid, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
>>> import mmap
>>> regs= mmap.mmap(fid, 4)
>>> regs.read(4)
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00'
>>> regs.seek(0)
>>> regs.write(b'\x65\x00\x00\x00')
>>> regs.seek(0)
>>> regs.read(4)
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00'
```

Can anyone explain why the other two approaches failed? From where I sit, they look equivalent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, UIO uses:

- `mmap()` to read and write the device address space
- `read()` to be notified of interrupts

So the behavior you are observing is correct.

See the [UIO HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/uio-howto.html) in the kernel documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I had seen that when originally reading about UIO, but it had completely slipped my mind.  This makes sense now.